# Unable to edit or post after enabling SSL

Tags: posts, ssl

After using certbot to enable SSL on my server, I'm unable to edit or create any posts on my wordpress site, any attempt to results in an "Updating failed" message

Attempting to preview posts leaves me on an endless loading screen.
There has been no errors in wp-content's debug.log
Enabling really simple SSL plugin has had no effect and disabling all plugins and themes has the same problem.
Wordpress address and Site address have already been updated to https:// in settings > general

any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried flushing permalinks? Sometimes not everything changes right away.

Step 1: In the main menu find "Settings > Permalinks".

Step 2: Scroll down if needed and click "Save Changes".

Step 3: Rewrite rules and permalinks are flushed.